Unable to use all (or most) of gym-retro games
My working ENV
System: ubuntu 18.04
Version: python 3.6/3.7/3.8(3 envvironments all the same result), gym 0.25.2, gym-retro 0.8.0
How did I do?
I follow this guide to install gym-retro. and I successfully run the example game.
Problems I met?
Firstly, I imported some ROMs from the internet, for example the the 128 sine-dot, But I CANNOT import it:
when I executed
python -m retro.import Anthrox\ -\ Sine-dot\ Demo\ \(PD\).smc

the result was:
Imported 0 games

picture of text above
and the Atari games (more than 1000 games),I could only successfully import no more than 200 games, but I can make env no more than 100 games.
I executed:
python -m retro.import .

and results was:
Importing DemonAttack-Atari2600
.
.
Importing Pong-Atari2600
Imported 167 games

I wrote this script to get game status to judge whether we can make this env:
import retro

game_list = retro.data.list_games()

def main():
    cnt = 0
    for game_name in game_list:
        try:
            env = retro.make(game=game_name)
        except Exception as e:
            print(game_name, ": ", "no")
        else:
            cnt+=1
            env.close()
            print(game_name, ": ", "yes")
    print("all: ", cnt)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

and the results was:
...
YarsRevenge-Atari2600 :  yes
YoukaiClub-Nes :  no
YoukaiDouchuuki-Nes :  no
YoungIndianaJonesChronicles-Nes :  no
Zanac-Nes :  no
Zaxxon-Atari2600 :  yes
ZeroTheKamikazeSquirrel-Genesis :  no
ZeroTheKamikazeSquirrel-Snes :  no
ZeroWing-Genesis :  no
ZombiesAteMyNeighbors-Snes :  no
ZoolNinjaOfTheNthDimension-Genesis :  no
ZoolNinjaOfTheNthDimension-Sms :  no
ZoolNinjaOfTheNthDimension-Snes :  no
all:  63

UPDATE INFO, all exceptions were:
Game not found: xxxxxxxx. Did you make sure to import the ROM?

and found out that only 63 games were makeable.
Questions I want to ask!!!
How could I import those games to my retro?

The first sentence from the guide/documentation you linked says: Gym Retro requires one of the supported versions of Python (3.5, 3.6, or 3.7) - and I see you use Python 3.8? This is not supported.

I have 3 environments, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, all the same situation.

All right, that's valuable info to have.

thanks, I forgot to add this to this post, I just added it.

What are the exceptions you catch but do not output?

Sorry, I rerun the code aboe: and the expection is :Game not found: YoukaiDouchuuki-Nes. Did you make sure to import the ROM?

So you have now a pointer where to look at. This might include reading the source of gym to find out what properties make a game found or not.

However, I'm missing the relation to programming. Wouldn't your issue be better addressed at some user forum? Or at SE/Superuser?

At least, I added 167 games, there should be 167 yes after I checked game status. However, thanks for your attention. I will post this issue to github.

I know why!!!
I had an assume: some games were imported successfully, but the retor's list_game cannot list it, so I want to figure out which game was imported but unlisted.
When I manually imported those games, I found many games in the ROMs have same name, forexample, "Robotank" occur 3 times, that's why I imported 167 games, but only have 59 in list. because there are same games in the ROMs. I use this ROMs.
